# How to make a table displayed with toggleClass remain open when a button within that table is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my database i have a table product_category, with products from a products table under each product category. I dynamically called out each product category in buttons, with each products under their specific product category on an HTML table. Each table remains hidden at first because of a class 'hide', but with jquery toggleClass, it gets displayed when their specific product category button is clicked on. But each table has buttons that open a modal and whenever i click on any i want that particular products table under it's product category to remain open. + even if i click on a space within the area or on the table itself and not even on a button, it gets closed. How can i restrict it to just the product category button.

[product category buttons on a fresh page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYQaB.jpg)

[product displayed when a product category is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6km4.jpg)

```
     <?php

    global $number;
    global $store_key;
    global $product_set;
    global $products;
    global $query;
    global $category;

    $store_key = $_SESSION['store_key'];
    //$branch_code = $_GET['branch_code'];    
       $query = "SELECT category_key FROM product_category WHERE store_key = '{$store_key}' ORDER BY category_name ASC";
        $category_set = mysql_query($query);
        if(!$category_set)
                    {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error().",  ".$query);
                    } 

      while($category = mysql_fetch_array($category_set)){
      ?>

  <ol id="chaps">
  <li><button class="button button-3d button-leaf" ><?php echo ucfirst(get_category($category['category_key']));?></button>

      <table id="datatable1" class="table table-striped table-bordered assignments hide" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <caption>Product Details</caption>
    <thead>
     <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Total Pieces</th>
          <?php 
        if($_SESSION['store_key'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){
            echo "<th>Action</th>";  
        }else{
            echo ""; 
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>

        <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Total Pieces</th>
          <?php 
        if($_SESSION['store_key'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){
            echo "<th>Action</th>";  
        }else{
            echo ""; 
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>





        <?php

    global $number;
    global $store_key;
    global $product_set;
    global $products;
    global $query;

    $store_key = $_SESSION['store_key'];
    //$branch_code = $_GET['branch_code'];    
    if($_SESSION['store_key'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){
       $query = "SELECT DISTINCT product_key,product_name FROM products WHERE store_key = '{$store_key}' AND category_key = '{$category['category_key']}' ORDER BY branch_code,product_name ASC";
        $product_set = mysql_query($query);
        if(!$product_set)
                    {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error().",  ".$query);
                } 
}else{
   $query = "SELECT DISTINCT product_key,product_name FROM products WHERE store_key = '{$store_key}' AND branch_code = '{$_SESSION['branch_code']}' AND category_key = '{$category['category_key']}' ORDER BY branch_code,product_name ASC";
    $product_set = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$product_set)
                {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error().",  ".$query);
                } 
}




  $number = mysql_num_rows($product_set);


  for($count=1;$count<=$number;$count++){ 
?>
<tr>
    <?php $products = mysql_fetch_array($product_set); ?>
        <?php echo "<td>{$count}</td>"; ?>  
    <?php echo "<td>".ucwords($products['product_name'])."</td>"; ?>
        <?php 
        if($_SESSION['store_key'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){
         echo "<td>".get_productPieces($products['product_key'])."</td>";   
        }else{
         echo "<td>".get_branchPieces($products['product_key'])."</td>";   
        }

        ?>

    <?php 
        if($_SESSION['store_key'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){
        echo "<td width='20px'>
            <a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' id='branch' data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target='#add_branchProductModal' href='modals/add_branchProductModal.php?id3={$_SESSION['store_key']}' role='button'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>";?>
        <!--<a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' href='productdelete.php' role='button'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>-->
          </td> 
          <?php
        }else{
            echo "";
        } 
            ?>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>

    </tbody>
      </table>


  </li>
</ol>
```

And my jquery that worked before i discovered my problem

```
    <script>
 $("#chaps > li").click(function() {
   $(this).find("table.assignments").toggleClass('hide');

});

                            </script>
```

then the one i tried to implement to solved the problem, it must be crappy tho cause i'm still learning jquery

```
<script>
   if($("#chaps > li").click()){
   $(this).find("table.assignments").toggleClass('hide');
   return true;
  }else if($("#branch").click()){ 
  $(this).find("table.assignments").toggleClass('hide');
  return false;
  }
                            </script>
```

Comment: I need a function that can over ride my 'hide' class, make the table display and close when i click the Product Category button only.

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the click event handler to the button not to the list item. Since the entire table is contained in the li tag, the handler is triggered anytime anything inside that tag is clicked. See if this works:

```
<script>
  if($("#chaps > li > button.button-leaf").click()){
   $(this).find("table.assignments").toggleClass('hide');
  return true;
 }else if($("#branch").click()){ 
 $(this).find("table.assignments").toggleClass('hide');
 return false;
 }
</script>
```

Edit:
In that case try this:

```
$('#chaps li').each(function () {
       $(this).find('button.button-leaf').on('click',function (){
           $(this).parents('li').find('table.assignments').toggleClass('hide');
             return false;
     });
});

$('#branch').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents('table.assignments').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

I did a similar test example to try it out: https://jsfiddle.net/zstj2nyn/ so it should be working

Comment: thank you very, much the table remains open when i click around it, unlike before. But it still closes when i click on the button within the table, that opens a modal. If you could help me with that i'll be really grateful.

Comment: i've solved it, and it works perfectly, thank you. i only added return false to the part with the branch id. but there is just a very minor problem. the modal button in the first table row closes the table, while the rest brings up the modal and the table still remains open.